# Let Cay(G, S) be the cayley graph of G with respect to the finite generating set S where G=⟨S∣R⟩ and R is finite.

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

Let $\operatorname{Cay}(G, S)$ be the cayley graph of $G$ with respect to the finite generating set $S$ where $G = \langle S\mid R\rangle$ and $R$ is finite.  I am reading some notes that claim that $π_1(\operatorname{Cay}(G, S)) = ⟨grg^{−1}⟩_{g∈G,r∈R}$.

They are here.  The paragraph above 8.1 on page 49.

http://www.math.ethz.ch/~alsisto/LectureNotesGGT.pdf

My problem is I looked the example $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} = \langle a,b\mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle$.  I do not see how I can find an element in $\langle grg^{−1}\rangle_{g∈G,r∈R}$ that equals say $a^{-2}ba^2b^{-1}$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Draw the cayley graph and trace out that word: it is the product of $a^{-1}(a^{-1}bab^{-1})a$ and $a^{-1}bab^{-1}$.

Comment: The product $grg^{-1}$ does not make sense, because $g$ and $r$ are not elements of the same group.